# Reading from a file using a getline

Tags: c++

There is a program that inputs a text file (text.txt) with two lines: the first line must be written to *input.txt*, and the second line must be written to the *expected_output* variable. The problem is that if the input file contains numbers - everything works fine, but if there are strings - the program outputs nonsense.

```
#include <fstream>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
 
int main() {       
    std::ifstream test_file("text.txt", std::ios::in);
    std::string input;
    std::string expected_output;
    std::string line;
    while (std::getline(test_file, line, '\n')) {
        input += line;
        std::getline(test_file, line, '\n');
        expected_output += line;
        std::cout << input << ";" << std::endl; 
        std::cout << expected_output << ";" << std::endl;

        std::ofstream input_file("input.txt");
        input_file << input;
        input_file.close();

        input.clear();
        expected_output.clear();
    } 
    return 0;
}
```

Example:
The input file text.txt contains the following:

```
lkhjgl
2
```

The program will write the string *lkhjgl\n2* to the input.txt, although it should write *lkhjgl*, and output it to the console:

```
2;hjgl
2;hjgl
```

although it should write:

```
lkhjgl;
2;
```

Comment: Looks like there's a `\r` in there.

Comment: please be exact about the details. Your code should also print `new test` to the console. Yes it is nitpicking, but yes we are nitpicking about just a couple of characters that come wrong

Comment: @463035818_is_not_a_number removed unnecessary output in the code!

Comment: still I'd expect two `;` in the output (in addition to the problem you want to get fixed). At least in the "it should write" there should be `;` at the end of the lines

Comment: Definitely some weird stuff going on with `\r`. Bottom line is that your files do not contain the characters you think they do. This is a common enough issue with unprintable characters like newlines and carriage return, spaces and tabs etc. Try and use a text editor that will show you every character explicitly (on Windows notepad++ is good for this).

Comment: @001 indeed, if remove `\r` with `line.erase(std::remove(line.begin(), line.end(), '\r'), line.end())` the output becomes more similar to what is needed, but still not what is needed. The line `lkhjgl2` is written to the file

Comment: Since you are trying to read two lines why do you have a loop? Why not just call getline twice? The way you have it blank lines at the end of your input could mess things up.

Comment: @001 Every other line of the input file.

Comment: @john The `text.txt` file is for black-box testing a program. In the file, the first line is for the input data, the second line is the expected result. Accordingly, the file `text.txt` can contain 2, 4, 6... lines. I hope I explained it clearly...

Comment: Thank you all! @john displaying all the characters in notepad++ helped. It is unclear how this happened, but the file was in Macintosh(CR) encoding....

Comment: Pro tip: don't name an output file `input_file`. <g>

Comment: This doesn't address the question, but there's a lot of thrashing in that code. If you define `input` and `expected_output` inside the `while` loop you won't have to call `clear()` each time at the end of the loop. Or you can leave their definitions where they are, remove `line`, and just read directly into `input` and `expected_output` in the `while` condition: `while (std::getline(test_file, input) && std::get line(test_file, expected_output) ...`. And you don't need to call `input_file.close();` -- the destructor will do that.

Comment: @PeteBecker Indeed, the code can be optimized. Thanks for the remark!